# Group pyspark dataframe by A, sort by B, then select first n distinct entries in C

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to group a given dataframe by column `A`. Each group then should be sorted by column `B`.  From each of those sorted groups I want to select `n` rows, namely those that contain the first `n` distinct values in column `C`. The chain of operations to do this should overall behave like a filter, that is all columns of the original dataframe should be included in the output dataframe.

Given `df`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    # FIRST GROUP (5 distinct C)
    # rows share [A, C]-combination
    [1, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2],
    # rows share [A, B]-combination
    [1, 3, 3, 3],
    [1, 3, 4, 4],
    # rows share [A, B, C]-combination
    [1, 4, 4, 5],
    [1, 4, 4, 6],
    # rows share only A
    [1, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 6, 7, 8],
    # SECOND GROUP (1 distinct C)
    # same A, B and C
    [2, 1, 1, 9],
    [2, 1, 1, 10],
], ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

the expected result for `n=4` is

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  3|  3|  3|
|  1|  3|  4|  4|
|  1|  5|  6|  7|
|  1|  6|  7|  8|
|  2|  1|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

If we'd ignore the necessity to keep `D` one possible solution to this problem would be this

```
first_n_distinct = (
    df
    .groupBy("A", "C")
    .agg(F.min("B").alias("B"))
    .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window
                                          .partitionBy("A")
                                          .orderBy("B")))
    .filter(F.col("rn") <= n)
)
```

The "best" way to end up with the desired result I found so far is to filter `df` based on the [A, B, C]-combinations in `first_n_distinct` and given duplicate rows exist in the result choose the one with the smallest `B` value.

```
df_subset_with_duplicates = (
    df
    .join(first_n_distinct, on=["A", "B", "C"], how="left")
    .filter(~F.isnull("rn"))
)
df_subset_first_n_distinct = (
    df_subset_with_duplicates
    .withColumn("rn2", F.row_number().over(Window
                                           .partitionBy("A", "B", "C")
                                           .orderBy("B")))
    .filter(F.col("rn2") == 1)
    .drop("rn2")
)
```

However, this seems not like the most efficient solution for this problem to me (but at least it seems to be a solution after all!). Does anybody know a better and easier to read/understand approach to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a `dense_rank` filter followed by a `row_number` filter:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

n = 4

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy('C'))
).filter(F.col('rn') <= n).withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('A', 'C').orderBy('B'))
).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')

df2.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  3|  3|  3|
|  1|  3|  4|  4|
|  1|  5|  6|  7|
|  2|  1|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Tanks for the answer! This solution works for the example dataframe. However, it is not a general solution to the described problem. Imagine `n=2` and in one group of `A` , `B` is [1, 2, 3] and `C` is [1, 3, 2]. In this case the first window of your solution would drop the second row (`C=3`), although the wanted output dataframe should consist of the first and second row

Comment: any other ideas?